# How to instantiate trait which extends class with constructor

Tags: scala

Have a code:

```
class A(name:String)
trait E extends A

new E{}  //compile error
```

Is such inheritance possible? Tried to create val or def in the body of anonymous class, doesn't help.

Comment: no. a Scala trait cannot extend a class, only other traits.

Comment: in fact a trait can extend a class but not call its constructor (which is the problem in this case). I even wonder why such a trait declaration compiles.

Comment: @SteveWaldman @sschaef Traits can extend classes, even with constructor arguments. `class B(name: String) extends A(name) with E` is an example of a completely fine way to use such a trait.

Comment: In this case you mix in the trait in a class, the question asks to extend a trait with a class which is a difference.

Comment: @sschaef Yeah, but the trait declaration itself is completely fine.

Comment: @ghik extending a class from a trait seems bizarre to me, but i'll admit i stand corrected! still, semantically, it must express more a constraint and a default than an ordinary class extensions. the ultimate, everything linearized class will have to extend the class, it must be impossible to extend an unrelated class and extend something else. the default class-to-extend becomes the trait extended, or if a class is extended explicitly, it must inherit from the one extended by the trait, and traits extending unrelated classes can't be mixed. no?

Comment: @SteveWaldman IMHO, the fact that traits can extend classes is very useful and it's one of the main advantages of traits over Java 8 default methods. About your intuition - yes, multiple class inheritance remains forbidden, so a trait extending a class can be thought of as a constraint or default superclass. Although be aware that it does more - e.g. it affects how the class is linearized. If you want just a constraint and nothing more then Scala has dedicated feature for this - self type annotations.

Comment: @ghik thanks. i'm still trying to grok why/when i might find this useful. as you say, self-types seem like a more natural way to constrain an implementation. it does seem potentially useful to nominate a default superclass, though that's countered by limitation on mixability. (but you'd get the same limitation of mixability with incompatible self-type constraints.) i'm still trying to make sense of the effect on linearization, when it'd be different from simply declaring the most derived trait superclass as superclass to the new class.

Comment: @SteveWaldman When you want to use _stackable_ traits where some trait method refers to the `super` implementation, then self-types are not enough. Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/ghik/11135240).

Comment: @ghik Thanks for taking the trouble to write that up! It is very clear, very straightforward. I wonder, though, why self types are insufficient for the compiler to allow super.work(). It knows with certainty that there will be such a method in any concrete implementation. Regardless, the limitation is real, and extending the class does circumvent it. Thank you again, I've learned something new.

Comment: @SteveWaldman My pleasure :) Inheritance relation is required to do any overriding and `super` calls. Self-type annotations don't introduce inheritance relation - they're merely a constraint on the classes that want to mix in the trait.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Few possible solutions:

1) set default value for **name** in class **A** constructor:

```
class A(name : String = "name")
trait E extends A
new E {} // {} is obligatory. trait E is abstract and cannot be instantiated`
```

2) mix trait **E** to instance of **A**:

```
object inst extends A("name") with E
// or:
new A("name") with E
```

Comment: Scala should forbidden triait extends class , it's useless since it can not be instantiated.

Comment: @WeiChingLin Nonsense! A trait that extends a class has access to the members of that class and can use them to compose methods that are only possible because of the requirements that the  _trait_ imposes. A trait extending a class is a totally normal and valid method of composition.

Answer (score 2):

`A` takes a constructor argument, so you are required to pass it, e.g.

```
new A("someName") with E
```

Comment: So I can't instantiate E starting with `new E`... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict trait E to be mixed with class A only you can use self type. However this is no way to define variable as new E with A(...)

```
class A(val name: String)

trait E { self: A =>
  def printName() = println(self.name)
}

val e = new A("This is A") with E
e.printName()
```